# how do I finish this conversion from SQL Server to Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a partially translate SQL script and several like it that look something like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE STATUSES
    ( STATUS_ID     CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
      DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
      EVENT         NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
      RESOLUTION    NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT PK_STATUSES PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (STATUS_ID ASC));
```

They were tables defined in SQL Server and I am looking to translate them for use in Oracle, however I am unsure how to handle the CLUSTERED part of the constraint and the ASC attribute of the Primary Key, I have seen some articles out there but they have served to be unhelpful. Can anyone help me complete this, or point me to an article that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ignore them.  You can remove both the `clustered` and the `asc` and the table should be fine in both databases.

I would be inclined to just use the `primary key` keyword, instead of an explicit `constraint`:

```
CREATE TABLE STATUSES (
  STATUS_ID     CHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  EVENT         NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  RESOLUTION    NUMBER(3) NOT NULL
);
```

Your table is too small to worry about clustered indexes.  It is questionable whether any index at all is useful on such a small table.

Comment: Ok I also have two tables that are ~20 columns and have a composite key of five columns all with ASC. How should I approach that?

Comment: @JBMac . . . Don't worry about the `asc`.

Comment: "*just use the primary key keyword, instead of an explicit constraint*" - which will generate a really ugly name for the PK. I find an error message "*unique constraint (PK_STATUSES) violated*" much easier to understand than "*unique constraint (SYS_C00109075) violated*" - especially if you need to analyze a logfile.

Comment: agreed with a_horse. The only unnamed constraints I allow are the NOT NULL constraints, which never need to be named anyway.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Interesting.  I always name `check` constraints and sometimes foreign key constraints.  Never primary key constraints, because I pretty much never get incidental violations of them (perhaps because I almost always use auto-incrementing primary keys).